# HTTP GET con Node recibe siempre contenido de index.html

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, http

Estoy tratando de hacer una peticion de tipo GET usando Node, React, Express.

Probe usando XMLHttpRequest, fetch, Axios, require(http/https) y siempre devuelve el contenido de la pagina principal.

Creo que deberia configurar algo en `./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js` pero no encuentro la solucion.

Tengo configurado el proyecto con este comando:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es el tutorial que hay en la pagina de React, estoy haciendo todo en el archivo `index.js` y ahora quiero agregar una conexion con la base de datos.

```
(simplificado)
app
├── node_modules
├── public
│   └── index.html
└── src
    └── index.js
```

Todavia no modifique nada de las rutas porque supuse que en el modulo de express no habia que tocar nada y en estos dos archivos si uso `require('express')` dejan de funcionar.

```
{
  "name": "my-app2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.2.7",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

---

./public/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

./src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import App from './App';
import  './index.css';


const products = [ 
  {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$49.99", stocked: true, name: "Football"},
  {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$9.99", stocked: true, name: "Baseball"},
  {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$29.99", stocked: false, name: "Basketball"},
  {category: "Electronics", price: "$99.99", stocked: true, name: "iPod Touch"},
  {category: "Electronics", price: "$399.99", stocked: false, name: "iPhone 5"},
  {category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7"}
]


class Todo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      check: false,
      filterText: '',
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(event){
    this.setState({check: !this.state.check});
  };
  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({filterText: event.target.value})
  }
  // filtrar = (ex) => {};
  render(){
    return(
      <fieldset >
        <legend>Productos</legend>
        <SearchBar
          checked={this.state.check}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        <ProductTable
          check={this.state.check}
          filter={this.state.filterText}/>
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
function SearchBar(props){
  return(
    <div style={{marginBottom: '5px'}}>
      <legend style={{color: 'grey', textAlign: 'left'}}>Filtrar:<br/>
        <input type="text" onChange={props.handleChange}/>
      </legend>
      <legend>
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={props.onChange}/>
        Mostrar solo en stock
      </legend>
    </div>
  );
}
function ProductTable(props){

  const cats = Array.from(new Set(products.map(x => x.category)));
  //const TagRandom = <p>holi</p>; // no funca
  return(
    <table>
      <tbody>
      {
        cats.map(x =>
          <React.Fragment key={x}>
            <ProductCategory category={x}/>
            {
              products.map(p =>
                (p.category === x) && (!props.check || p.stocked) ?
                <ProductRow key={p.name} name={p.name} price={p.price} filter={props.filter}/> :
                null)
            }
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
function ProductCategory(props){
  return(
    <tr style={{color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#444'}}>
    <th colSpan="2">
      {props.category}
    </th>
    </tr>
  )
}
function contiene(str, filtro){
  if(!filtro) return true;
  let a = str.toLowerCase();
  let b = filtro.toLowerCase();
  if(a.includes(b)) return true;
  return false;
}
function ProductRow(props){
  if(!contiene(props.name, props.filter)) return null;
  return(
      <tr >
        <td>{props.name}</td>
        <td>{props.price}</td>
      </tr>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Todo />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

---

Estuve buscando donde configurar las rutas pero no le encuentro la vuelta. Incluso borre el `./public/index.html` en donde se renderiza `./src/index.js` y la aplicacion sigue funcionando normalmente. No tengo indea de cual es el primer archivo que es llamado cuando uso `npm start` (donde supongo que hay que configurar las rutas).

Comment: Hola, ¿ya has configurado las rutas? Si lo has hecho ¿podrías postear el código de las mismas? Saludos

Comment: Hola. No creo que haga falta agregar el codigo en este caso, el .html es un html comun y corriente y el .js renderiza una tabla de productos bastante basica. Pero si crees que vale la pena lo subo.

Comment: En otro proyecto parecido vi que el package.json tenia una linea que decia `"main": "index.js"`, creo que la pagina principal del servidor deberia ser .js y tener ahi las rutas. Mas tarde voy a probar eso a ver si funciona.

Comment: Creo que tienes una pequeña confusión con React. Es un framework para proyectos web del lado cliente (Frontend). Según la [documentación](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app), *Create React App* no maneja la lógica del backend o de base de datos, solo crea una estructura esqueleto de frontend para que puedas usarlo con el backend de tu preferencia (Express-Node, Laravel-PHP, Django-Python, SrpingBoot-Java, .Net Core, etc.). Es en el back end que vas a manejar la lógica de conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: Si, ayer me entere de que era solo para frontend, empece a usarlo hace muy poco. La cuestion es que no se como hacer las peticiones al servidor ahora, supongo que es por el tema del enrutamiento que debe bloquear todas las rutas que no esten especificadas o algo asi.

Comment: Dices: ***no se como hacer las peticiones al servidor***, ¿a qué servidor, ya tienes un servidor back end funcionando? Me gustaría ayudarte, pero me parece que debes dar más contexto. Saludos

Comment: Perdon la demora. Lo que estoy haciendo es exactamente esto: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html tengo un servidor local funcionando con node en localhost:3000 y lo que quiero es en vez de usar la lista de productos hardcodeada usar mongodb. Pero siempre que hago una peticion get me devuelve el html de la pagina principal. Estoy casi seguro que es por no configurar las rutas y ahora tengo mas o menos una idea de como tendria que hacerlo, mas tarde lo pruebo y aviso como me fue. Mientras si a alguien se le ocurre que puede estar pasando agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: Ya pude configurar las rutas modificando el package.json de `"start": "react-scripts start" -> "node index"`. Ahora no se como devolver lo que renderiza React, pero creo que ya seria materia para otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado cambiando `"start": "react-scripts start"` por `"node index"` y configurando las rutas en ese archivo.